# Why do delegates exist in iOS?

Tags: ios, delegates

I understand that delegates are essentially objects that another object can pass messages to, and that they are used on behalf of other classes. So for example, a `UITableViewDelegate` has methods which can be used to detect particular events in a `UITableView`. This is very useful, and indeed I have used delegates a lot in past iOS projects, so this is more of a curiosity:

**Why do the methods in a delegate class not just exist in the class that the delegate is being delegated by?**

Surely it would be more convenient to have those methods in the actual class, such as a `UITableView`?

Perhaps it is that architecturally it is more convenient, but from fist looks it seems counter intuitive.

Comment: But your view controller (typically) is a table view's data source because the table view doesn't know anything about its data.

Comment: How would you be notified that a cell was selected if the `UITableViewDelegate` methods were methods in `UITableView`?

Comment: A `UITableView` is a view. It should not know about the model. So it asks the `ViewController` about how many items it should have, which content and so on. It separates the responsibilities.

Comment: @user2419986 protocol in swift is similar to interfaces in Java.where we have only method name but no method definition.If marked abstract you need to implement all methods in your class.so in swift you have protocol with required and optional delegate methods.swift don't support multiple inheritance so there is the concept of protocol and delegate.because a class can implement multiple protocol.So we overcoming multiple inheritance issue with this. .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, composition is more powerful than inheritance. Inheritance creates many subtle problems, the most common of which is the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem), but there are many other problems.

Delegation is just a specific formulation of the Strategy pattern, which allows us to extend an object via composition rather than inheritance.

As a concrete example of the issue, and how the diamond problem creeps in when you use inheritance, consider this:

- You have a very common way you want to provide cells. For example, you'd like a Core Data fetch request, or a network request that generates cells. So you would build a superclass that encapsulated all this logic. We'll call the class that handles that`FetchRequestDataProviding`.
- Separately, you have a visual behavior you use a lot. For example, you want a particular kind of animations for your view, so you wrap that up into a class `FadeInTableView`.

Now we have a problem because we want both. So we need multiple inheritance. And multiple inheritance is Pandora's box of ambiguities.

But I eliminate all of that if I make `FetchRequestDataProviding` a separate object that behaves as a delegate. I actually could make things even more powerful by breaking out `FadeInAnimating` as a delegate/strategy (though `UIView` doesn't have that power today).

In ObjC, "composition is more powerful than inheritance" shows itself commonly in a fairly shallow inheritance tree and lots of delegates. Swift pushes this further with protocols and structs that have no inheritance. None of this means that inheritance is bad; it can have a lot of value (though languages like Go avoid it entirely; though interestingly still has to face the diamond problem due to embedding). But when in doubt, composition is the more powerful tool.